# make only a particular window active until it is closed in js

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML page which I have opened in a new window. Now I want only that new window to be active until it is closed using close button (cursor should work on the new window only).
I have tried using window.focus() but I don't think it is the right way to do so.

```
var mywindow = window.open("editparameter.html", "Modify","height=600,width=800,left= 300,top = 100, location = no, modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
mywindow.focus();
```

This is the code I have written in my current page. Here `editparameter.html` is the page that opens in the new window.

Comment: hope you can use bootstrap modals. here is an example - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you want to block your page or do something else while child tab is opened, you can open new tab and wait its close:

```
function open() {
  // do something with current tab
  const tab = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  tab.onclose = onTabClosed;
}

function onTabClosed() {
  // revert what has been done
}
```

Comment: For instance to disable page you can set `* { pointer-event: none }` it will disable all of the mouse events.

Comment: Or as it has already been recommended try using modals, it would be better in terms of UX

Comment: i do not want to use bootstrap.

Comment: @Himanshu <dialog id="modal"></dialog> ... document.getElementById("modal").showModal() is not bootstrap